# How would say someone had a "thick" or "broad" accent?

Tags: translation, word-choice

Like if you were saying "he has a thick accent" or "he has a broad accent."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what a "broad accent" is - but if their native language is coming on clearly through their accent, the best way to say this is ***forta akĉento.***